# Turtle not animating more than one charchter

Tags: python, animation, graphics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want multiple turtles to move across the screen but only one object gets animated. Also, I want the two objects to go in opposite directions as it is part of the game (Similar to frogger). The harm objects are in the list 'game_objects' and type= 'harm and their direction is giving I got the first one to work right to left but not the other one which goes from left to right.

```
    game_objects = [{'t':turtle.Turtle(),'x': 0, 'y': -140, 'radius': 10, 'image': 
    'pikachu.gif', 'speed': 1, 'type':'player', 'direction':''}, 
    {'t':turtle.Turtle(), 'y': 0, 'image': 'gym.gif', 
    'type':'harm', 'direction':'left'}, {'t':turtle.Turtle(), 'y': -80,'image': 'gym.gif', 'type':'harm', 'direction':'right'}]
   
    def main():
      global sc
      global player
      sc = turtle.Screen()
      sc.setup(width=300, height=300)
      sc.bgcolor("black")
      sc.bgpic('ezgif.com-gif-maker (3).gif')
      sc.tracer(0)
      w, h = sc.screensize()
      sc.addshape('pikachu.gif')
      pikachu = game_objects[0]

    def animate (x,speed,  y , path):
      global sc
      sc.addshape(x['image'])
      if x['type'] == 'harm':
        if path == 'left':
          x['t'].speed(0)
          x['t'].shape("gym.gif")         
          x['t'].penup()
          x['t'].goto(-100, y)
          while True :
            if x['t'].xcor() < 160:
              sc.update()
              x['t'].forward(speed)
            else:
              x['t'].goto(-150,y)
        else:
          x['t'].speed(0)
          x['t'].shape("gym.gif")         
          x['t'].penup()
          x['t'].goto(-100, y)
          while True:
            if player.distance(x['t']) < 25:
              update_values(1, 1)
              player.goto(0,-120)
            if x['t'].xcor() < -160:
              sc.update()
              x['t'].backward(speed)
            else:
              x['t'].goto(150,y)

      main()


      for b in game_objects:
         animate(b,0.04, b['y'], b['direction'])
```

Comment: how do you intend to get out of that while true loop? also what's with the main call there?

Comment: I am not sure how to get out of the loop as I need it to animate the object.

Comment: when doing animations think about actions to generate one frame at a time.  This can involve looping over all your turtles once and changing them to their next appearance.  Then do a loop around generating a frame.  watch what happens when you change that while true to a range based loop.  you might see what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a loop around frames.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using the `ontimer()` method of screen to replace your `while True:` loops which have no place in an event-driven world like turtle.  Below is a stripped down version of your code that moves two objects across the screen in opposite directions at different speeds:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

TRUE_WIDTH, TRUE_HEIGHT = 300, 300

CHROME = 14  # magic number possibly derivable from tkinter

WIDTH, HEIGHT = TRUE_WIDTH + CHROME, TRUE_HEIGHT + CHROME # need to be slightly larger

IMAGE_SIZE = 20  # cursor size for this example; for your code, the size of the gif images

game_objects = [
    {'t': Turtle(), 'y': 0, 'image': 'circle', 'type':'harm', 'direction':'left', 'speed': 0.4},
    {'t': Turtle(), 'y': -80, 'image': 'square', 'type':'harm', 'direction':'right', 'speed': 0.8}
]

def initialize(game_object):
    # screen.addshape(game_object['image'])

    turtle = game_object['t']
    turtle.shape(game_object['image'])
    turtle.penup()

    direction = game_object['direction']

    if direction == 'right':
        turtle.goto(-100, game_object['y'])
    elif direction == 'left':
        turtle.goto(100, game_object['y'])

    screen.update()

def animate(game_object):
    if game_object['type'] == 'harm':
        turtle = game_object['t']

        if game_object['direction'] == 'right':
            if turtle.xcor() < IMAGE_SIZE + TRUE_WIDTH/2:
                turtle.forward(game_object['speed'])
            else:
                turtle.goto(-IMAGE_SIZE - TRUE_WIDTH/2, game_object['y'])
        elif game_object['direction'] == 'left':
            if turtle.xcor() > -IMAGE_SIZE - TRUE_WIDTH/2:
                turtle.backward(game_object['speed'])
            else:
                turtle.goto(IMAGE_SIZE + TRUE_WIDTH/2, game_object['y'])

        screen.update()

    screen.ontimer(lambda: animate(game_object), 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.screensize(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)  # backing store needs to be smaller than window
screen.tracer(False)

for game_object in game_objects:
    initialize(game_object)
    animate(game_object)

screen.mainloop()
```

Since I don't have your GIF images, I've switched it to cursor shapes.  I've also added code to help when working with small windows in turtle.  (Small windows suffer more from unnecesary scroll bars and loss of area from window chrome.)  Also, reread about the proper use of the `global` keyword.